# Como pasar el nombre de una foto para mostrarla en html

Tags: html, flask

Bueno mi problema es simple de explicar, no se como mostrar una foto si le paso el nombre como una variable usando url_for() en html , probablemente el error sea muy simple pero la verdad soy un noob. Gracias de antemano. Les dejo el codigo.

Flask, agregar foto:

```
@app.route('/agregar', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def agregar():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['Foto']
        filename = file.filename
        file.save( os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER_HOSTAL'], filename ))

        new_hostal = Hostal(nombre=request.form['Nombre'], ubicacion=request.form['Ubicacion'], habitaciones=request.form['Cantidad'],Beneficios=7, banio=request.form['Bano'], cocina=request.form['Cocina'],descripcion=request.form['Descripcion'], precio=request.form['Precio'],foto = filename )
        db.session.add( new_hostal )
        db.session.commit()

        return redirect( url_for('Busqueda') )

    return render_template('agregar.html')
```

Flask, enviar variables:

```
@app.route('/buscar')
def Busqueda():

    hostales = Hostal.query.all()
    return render_template('Busqueda.html', hostales = hostales )
```

HTML :

```
<div id="Hostales">
    {% for hostal in hostales %}
        <div class="Hostal">
            <div class="datos">
                <h1> {{ hostal.nombre }} </h1>
                <h2> Ubicacion: {{ hostal.ubicacion }} </h2> <br>
                <h2> {{ hostal.descripcion }} </h2> <br>
                <h2> Precio: {{ hostal.precio }} </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="foto">
                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/HostaPic/{{ hostal.foto }}')}}">
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: No entiendo bien tu problema. ¿Puedes ser un poco más específico?

Comment: ¿A qué url te estás refiriendo con `url_for('Busqueda')`?

Comment: @PepoGonzalez Mi problema es que guardo el nombre de la foto en un formulario y no puedo mostrarla y no se porque

Comment: @ÁlvaroMondéjar el `url_for('Busqueda')` es para que cuando el request es de metodo post se redirecciona a la funcion busqueda